# Updated and saving HighScore

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

Been tooling with a highscore all night. I can get it to update however it doesn't save from game to game nor when app closes. i.e. If you made 8 points that game your score/high score is 8. if you make 3 points the following game your score is 3 and high score is 3 when it should still be 8. What am I missing?

```
    //Score Display

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int _score = [prefs integerForKey:@"score"];
    SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ChalkDuster"];
    //Other label node configuration here
    scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,325);
    scoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",_score];
    [self addChild:scoreLabel];

    //High Score
    NSUserDefaults *prefs2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int _highscore = [prefs2 integerForKey:@"highscore"];
    SKLabelNode *highScoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ChalkDuster"];
    highScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,275);
    highScoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %d",_highscore];
    [self addChild:highScoreLabel];

    if(_score > _highscore){
        _highscore = _score;
                 int _highscore = [prefs2 integerForKey:@"highscore"];
                highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %d",_highscore];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking _score > _highscore
but you're never setting the highscore back into prefs2.  You're reading it back out, but not putting it in.

need something like 
    `[prefs2 setInteger:_highscore forKey:@"hightscore"]`

Comment: Had to reorganize the code and added what you suggested. Worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to have prefs and prefs2.  They are in fact pointing to the same place.  Just get standardUserDefaults once and reuse prefs over and over.